# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because the expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 1: number; 2: number; 3: number; }'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

The following code throws:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because the expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 1: number; 2: number; 3: number; }'.
```

```
const obj = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
}

fetch('http://example.com/foo.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  //                         throws
  .then(data => console.log(obj[data]))
```

Instead of listing all possible keys:

```
const obj = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
}

fetch('http://example.com/foo.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  //                                  list all possible keys
  .then(data => console.log(obj[data as 1 | 2 | 3]))
```

Is there a better way for fixing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner:

```
const obj = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
}

fetch('http://example.com/foo.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  //                                  one-liner
  .then(data => console.log(obj[data as keyof typeof obj]))
```